# Can we earn the Organizer badge without having required rep?

Tags: support, tags, reputation, badges

I earned the [*Organizer* badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/5/organizer) without having the required reputation, but re-tagging in the editing section. Later, I saw that I have passed the required rep and granted the re-tagging permission.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can earn in with `1` reputation too, While doing editing and if you find that the tags are not properly added by the OP, in that case you can add the proper tag. When this **Suggested Edit** gets approved, you earn `2` points with the `Organizer` badge.

So, basically you earn **Organizer** badge for proper tagging the question.

However it requires 500 reputation to get the *[Retag questions privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions)* and see a 'retag' option in the question. Simple editing the tags does not give you any reputation.

Comment: do we earn 2 points each time we re-tag?

Comment: thanks,i have updated my answer @DR, kindly check it.

Comment: I will add to the last part - direct editing of a post (title, tags or body) grants no reputation so after you gain 2K reputation you can no longer gain reputation from edits as you gain the edit privilege.

Comment: Thank you for adding information @ShaDowWizArd