# what is mean by score?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, score

What is mean by "score"? Is it total of up votes and down votes? Because I have [2 up voted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135596/can-we-earn-the-organizer-badge-without-having-required-rep) but don't have `Quorum` badge in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes, it's total of upvotes and downvotes, with downvotes being a negative number.

Comment: so why I don't have 'Quorum' badge yet?

Comment: Umm patience? [You just got it...](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1244383/d-r?tab=activity&sort=badges)

Comment: @animuson: Ok, then I'll wait. I confused that some badges are granted quickly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question with a total score (the number shown beside the post) of +2 qualifies for [the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/900/quorum), but badges are not issued immediately.  The process that calculates badges may take a day to run.

Comment: Ok, then I'll wait. I confused that some badges are granted quickly. :)

Comment: @DR as noted in a comment above, you apparently have the badge now. I think badges are issued faster now than they once were: it used to be standard to have to wait until the next day.